# How could I get a stack trace or set a breakpoint for every time/place a jQuery UI widget's options change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, debugging

I have a fairly complex set of jQuery UI widgets that interact with each other, often times asynchronously. I have a situation where a particular widget's `options` data is being altered  unexpectedly, not via `_setOption` or `_setOptions`.

Is there any way, in Chrome, Safari or Firefox, to get a stack trace logged or set a breakpoint for whenever that widget's `options` data gets changed? It seems like there should be a way to watch a value in memory and get alerted whenever it's accessed or altered.

Answer (score 0):

[FireQuery](https://github.com/binaryage/firequery) or [jQuery Lint](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Lint) should report this, and both can be extended to set a breakpoint in this particular case to help debug the root cause of the event in the call stack.